# Need to create a duplicate of word file using XSL Transformation

Tags: xml, shell, xslt, dita, oxygenxml

I'm having project (test.xpr) which converting Word to Dita(xml) using the Oxygen XML Editor. In the Transformation Scenario, I have mentioned the Comments.xml of Word file as XML URL Input and I have set the XSL file in the XSL URL path. Then I'm using Saxon-PE 9.6.0.7. In the parameter, I have included CommentsExtractURL value as the word document xml file.

[image]

I want to make a duplicate of the word document in some other path and I have to replace the comments.xml (which is output file of the transformation) of the corresponding file while running the transformation. Is that I need to write anything on the shell script or XSLT or any other way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oxygen XML Editor transformation scenarios do not allow you to save the result of an XSLT transformation directly inside a zip archive. 
So you would need a multi step process. Maybe an ANT build file which unpacks the DOCX archive, applies the XSLT and then packs the DOCX again.